# if i use FILTER_SANITIZE_URL will it change my url

Tags: php, regex

i have the url which looks this

```
http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery?id=%2527759349-submenuid%2527
```

now i want my url to look neat and clean something like

```
http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery/2527759349/2527
```

i don't even it is possible but i would like my url to look good now i have heard about this function in php FILTER_SANITIZE_URL using this will it make my url look good

Comment: All the frameworks do this by using their own technique. But if u r using plain PHP then try to use any PHP route like - https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute

Comment: are you taking about this `http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery?id=%2527759349-submenuid%2527` as a string or actual URL on browser?

Comment: In answer to your question "will it change my url" - no. `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` is used to help remove harmful characters from a string. I think, if you are using `apache`, then you might wish to look at creating some `rewrite rules` in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @RamRaider thanks but i have been searching for this like month do you know any website which can resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website the structure of the urls in the menu system appear a little different to what you cited above.

For instance: `http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery.php?id='496720-submenuid'`

I don't see the subsequent `submenuid` in the url so I'm not 100% sure if what follows is more or less what you are attempting to do.

```
RewriteRule ^civil-gallery/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /civil-gallery.php?id=$1-submenuid=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:civil-gallery\.php)?\?id=([^&\s]+)-submenuid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /civil-gallery/%1/%2\? [R=302,L,NE]
```

So, if you were to enter ( in the browser's address bar ) a url like

```
http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery.php?id=98765-submenuid=12345
```

It would be re-written to

```
http://www.skymount.in/civil-gallery/98765/12345
```

Comment: i pasted the above code but now i am not able to view the page it says no page available